# Changing the default version of python for Ned Batchelder's coverage tool

Tags: python, coverage.py, python-coverage

The title pretty much says it.  I'm having problems connected to the change in the `unittest` python from python 2.5 to 2.7.  When I run my test script with python

```
python _tester.py
```

it works fine.  But when I try to use the coverage tool

```
coverage erase; coverage run _tester.py; coverage html -d html_cov_report
```

it crashes saying that `assertRaisesRegexp` is not an attribute of my subclass of `TestCase`.  I discovered that this was because the coverage tool was using python 2.5 and `unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegexp` does not exist in 2.5.

Anyway, can somebody tell me how to change the python used by coverage?

EDIT:  The egg for coverage is in /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages. Does that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `coverage` script should have a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) that can be changed to the right version of python.

Edit: If you installed it in python 2.5, it is probably easiest to switch to installing using python 2.7.

Comment: There is at least 36 files in the coverage dir.  I looked in the ones that looked like likely "run" modules (__init__.py, exec_file.py,...) but didn't see any shebangs at the top.  Should I add one?

Comment: Please don't try to edit the coverage.py files.  Just re-install it into the Python installation you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of 4 options (with order of what should be done IMHO):

1. You can install `coverage` under python2.7 and not python 2.5.
2. I think this should be fixed if you run the `coverage` script using python 2.7: `/path/to/python2.7 /path/to/coverage ...`, assuming that python2.5 is the default one.
3. use [unittest2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2/).
4. you can change the default python to python 2.7 as i believe `coverage` script shebang should be `/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: I used easy_install to install coverage (I'm on a mac).  Is there a way I can specify which version of python to install it for, using easy_install?

Comment: what's your default python ? ``python -V``.

Comment: Ok my **first** guess was wrong ;-), can you do ``which coverage`` and check the shebang it should be ``/usr/bin/env python`` and check if it's pointing to python 2.7, b/c if it's pointing to python2.5 then there is your problem; you will have to remove the current ``coverage`` package and install it again and check that it's using python 2.7, hope i get it right this time.

Comment: Aha!  The python the shebang points to is version 2.5.4.  Forgot about the "which" command.  Thanks!

Comment: @Harrison: Glad you found your solution :)